# How to take a screenshot with Aero effects?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, screenshot, aero

I don't want to make a normal screenshot. I want to make a screenshot that includes Aero glass, drop shadows, etc. in "transparent" mode.

I tried some tools like Windows Clippings, but the Aero glass is gray instead of blue, I want to take a screenshot that captures the color of the Aero glass.

Checkout this example I found in Google Images, this screenshot demonstrates it IS possible to take a screenshot with transparent Aero glass.

[image]

As the image suggests, the default color of Aero glass wasn't lost or removed in the screenshot.

How do I take a screenshot like this?

Comment: I've removed the off-topic software request portion of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Screenshot Captor from [Donationcoder](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html) can do that. From their help file:

> "Perfect capture of Windows 7 partial transparency effects"

Comment: I've tested and it really fit my needs, thanks a lot

Comment: P.S.: The only cons of the software is: I can't capture the Aero shadows, I guess the issue is the settings, but at least it does what I needed, "The Aero glass".